# reCAPTCHA: Multiple callbacks doesn't work

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm creating a login and signup system and to avoid bots, i'm using google recaptcha and i'm trying to use multiple callbacks to send form data to the server via ajax request and this appeared in console:

> ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: [object Object]

This is the code (the problem is in the line 4):

```js
$(window).on('load',function(){
    grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
        'sitekey' : '6LcFrN8cAAAAAMr2P3Nkvm7fDFzIykf30QykYlga',
        'callback' : {onSubmitLogin, onSubmitSignUp},
        'size' : 'invisible'
        });
});

//Login
$('#login').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.execute();          
    }
);

function onSubmitLogin(token){
    var formEmail = $('#email-login').val();
    var formPasswd = $('#password-login').val();
    var reCaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'account.php?action=login',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {formEmail, formPasswd, reCaptchaResponse},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() { $('#loading').fadeIn("slow"); },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loading').fadeOut("slow");
            grecaptcha.reset();
        },
        success: function(response){
            if(response.status == 'error'){
                $('#alert-container').prepend('<div class="alert ' + response.status + ' showAlert"><div class="alert-content"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i><p>' + response.message + '</p></div><button class="alert-close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></div>');
            }else if(response.status == 'success'){
                window.location = "dashboard";
            }
        }
    })
};

//SignUp
$('#signup').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.execute();          
    }
);

function onSubmitSignUp(token){
    var formEmail = $('#email-sign-up').val();
    var formPasswd = $('#password-sign-up').val();
    var formConfirmPasswd = $('#confirm-password-sign-up').val();
    var reCaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'account.php?action=create',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {formEmail, formPasswd, formConfirmPasswd, reCaptchaResponse},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() { $('#loading').fadeIn("slow"); },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loading').fadeOut("slow");
            grecaptcha.reset();
        },
        success: function(response){
            $('#alert-container').prepend('<div class="alert ' + response.status + ' showAlert"><div class="alert-content"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i><p>' + response.message + '</p></div><button class="alert-close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></div>');
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do something like this instead?

```
grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
    'sitekey' : '6LcFrN8cAAAAAMr2P3Nkvm7fDFzIykf30QykYlga',
    'callback' : () => {
        onSubmitLogin();
        onSubmitSignUp();
     },
    'size' : 'invisible'
});
```

Comment: It kinda works, but now it's submiting both forms

Comment: I see, makes sense now that I read the code again. so you need to duplicate that code and have one for each form I guess, but not too sure how to go about it, probably read the recaptcha docs.